# How to solve this without multiple inheritance?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, class-design, multiple-inheritance

I have class named `Controller_Home`. It should inherit from `Controller_Permissions` and `Controller_Template`. Any class prefixed with `Controller_` must inherit from `Controller` class.

If multiple inheritance would be supported in PHP (my case), I could do like this:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Permissions, Controller_Template {
```

And `Controller_Permissions`, `Controller_Template`:

```
Controller_Permissions extends Controller {

Controller_Template extends Controller {
```

Now I need to do something like this:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Template {

class Controller_Permissions extends Controller_Template {

Controller_Template extends Controller {
```

Okay, it works!

Now I need to use `Controller_Template` without permissions (in `Controller_Permissions`).

How to do it without duplicating code? I don't want another class `Controller_TemplateWithoutPermissions`.

Controllers, templates and permissions is just for example.

Comment: You assume that multiple inheritance solves this problem in a pretty way. I disagree and I guess most answers you will get will be same. I recommend you to change the title to something like: 'how to solve this without multiple inheritance'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common alternative to multiple inheritance is to use composition. This makes the relationship a "has a" as opposed to an "is a" relationship. Ie in your example above you might have ControllerHome inherit from ControllerTemplate but hold some ControllerPermissions as a variable. This way ControllerHome **is a** ControllerTemplate and **has a** ControllerPermissions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Traits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29) in this situation.

> Traits are similar to mixins, but whereas mixins can be composed only using the inheritance operation, traits offer a much wider selection of operations, including symmetric sum, method exclusion, and aliasing. A Trait differs from an abstract type in that it provides implementations of its methods, not just type signatures.

Traits is available in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and is common in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/).

Comment: Sounds good, but there's a little problem... PHP 5.4. Any other solutions, people? :)

Comment: @daGrevis I wish I could downvote comments. This one was pretty pointless and trollesque. Actually, given the poor knowledge you have (that's quite visible in your question) I wonder how you can judge weither a language is good or not.

Comment: @deadalnix PHP 5.4 may not be available to him or his client.

Comment: @leo, this may be true, but is out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing pretty about that at all. All of your classes are very tightly coupled together. Defining, and then implementing interfaces on the objects, and using aggregation to build up the 'with permissions' and 'without permissions' types is a cleaner, and 'prettier' solution. It also allows for IoC (which breaks encapsulation if you're a staunch SOLID person), which gives you better unit testing scenarios, and allows for the use of a DI container.